# AngularJS $resouce is adding $resolved and $promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fetching the data  using $resource in AngularJS.

However , it is adding two additional properties $promise and $resolved in result.  Below is my code. How could I get around this ?

```
myStoreCheckoutService.factory('Checkout',function($resource){

    return $resource('assets/app/data/billing/:file.json', {}, {
      getSalexTax: {method:'GET', params:{file:'sales-tax'}, isArray:false}      
    });

})



myStoreCheckoutControllers.controller('myStoreCheckoutCtrl',function($scope,Checkout){


    $scope.states=[];


    $scope.saleTaxMaster=Checkout.getSalexTax((function(){
        console.log($scope.saleTaxMaster);
        getStates();
    })); 


    function getStates(){
        for(var x in $scope.saleTaxMaster){
            if($scope.saleTaxMaster.hasOwnProperty(x)){
                $scope.states.push(x);              
            }   
        }
    }   

})
```

Here my `$scope.saleTaxMaster` has both those properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is a design/feature of $resource. If this is an issue, you can skip properties starting with $, this is a common pattern in some Angular functions like `angular.toJson(x)`. This is how Angular itself keeps the $promise and $resolved from appearing when you send the modified entity back to the server. Another alternative is to use $http, which doesn't modify the object returned.